# What versions of Windows ship with ICACLS

Tags: windows, icacls

Can someone point me to a list somewhere that states which versions of Windows (client and server) ship with ICACLS?  I need to know going back to approximately the Windows XP era, and unfortunately don't have access to baseline images (someone may have manually put ICACLS on the machine if it did not have it).

Comment: I just did a google search **Icacls is a command-line utility that can be used to modify NTFS file system permissions in Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista ...** and of course **icacls.exe (included in Windows Server 2003 SP2 and later)**

Comment: Does Windows XP ship it? I am assuming not since it predates Server 2003.  Also, does a baseline Server 2003 install (non sp2) not include it?

Comment: I have no idea. I found that information based on a Google search. I would assume the utility was there by default or easily installed through Windows Features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, ICACLS is not available in Windows XP.**

ICACLS ships starting from Windows Server 2003, i.e., from **Windows Vista era** onwards.

For previous versions of Windows such as XP, use [CACLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) instead.